# get dynamically generated form data in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am adding multiple inputs by sizes array that looks like this

```
[
 {
   _id: "1",
   size: "Size 1",
   price: 2
 },
 {
   _id: "2",
   size: "Size 2",
   price: 4
 }
]
```

In the form like this

```
<Form onSubmit={this.addToppingAction}>
  <div>
    <label className="col-form-label" htmlFor="topping">
      Topping
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="topping" value={topping} placeholder="Topping" />
  </div>
  <h5>Sizes</h5>
  {sizes.map(size => (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="price">{size.size} price</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        step="0.1"
        id={size._id}
        name="price"
        value={size.price}
        placeholder="Price"
      />
    </div>
  ))}

  <button type="submit">Add Toppings</button>
</Form>;
```

To explain further I am creating a Point of sale for pizza restaurant I am adding multiple sizes of pizza from different from different view.

In this one I want to define the price of toppings based on different sizes.

I am trying to find the solution to get the below mentioned result on form submit like this.

```
{
  name: "topping name",
  size: [
   {
      price: 1,
      size: "size 1"
   },

   {
      price: 2,
      size: "size 2"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing these states/values?

Comment: hi it is confused ,which format you want to input whether top or buttom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can
[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bell-4nx7m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to get the solution.

as Main part is this.

```
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sizes:[{price:"a",name:"b"},{price:"c",name:"f"}]
    }
    // you can set state from api or ... you know how you are setting.
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (e){
    let newState = Object.assign([],this.state.sizes);
    newState[e.target.name.split("_")[0]][e.target.name.split("_")[1]] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({sizes:newState})
  }

  handleSubmit(){
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render(){
    const {sizes} = {...this.state}
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {sizes.map( (data,index)=>
          <div>
            {Object.keys(data).map( d => <input name={`${index}_${d}`} value={data[d]} onChange={this.handleChange} />)}
          </div>
        )}
        <button onClick={()=>this.handleSubmit()} >test</button>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

But ..

Nesting state is not recommended in react docs. As it make harder for react to update.So try to avoid nesting states like you are doing here.

```
{
stateA:{
  stateB:{
    react:"angry"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not nested states please see my edited question.

Comment: @Abdul-RafayShaikh Okay then the code will work fine for you. You only need to use your array instead of `this.state.a` .

Comment: @Abdul-RafayShaikh and let me know if it work for you. + you can also try editing code in given line.